# Верны ли знаки препинания в моем предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении: «Распоряжение, что храм передаётся обновленцам, было выдано НКВД Крымской АССР 2 декабря 1922 года». Верны ли запятые?

Comment: Да, всё верно..

Comment: выдано КЕМ....А что?

Comment: FlossyU, здесь теоретически можно прочитать не "выдано (кем?) НКВД" , а "выдано (кому?) НКВД".

Comment: *Распоряжение о передаче храма обновленцам было выдано*... (Такое снимет головную боль.)